# PyPDF2 decoding issue when adding annotations in Chinese characters with addJS

Tags: javascript, pdf, annotations, decoding, pypdf

I want to use PyPDF2 to add annotations programmatically with the use of addJS, it works very well for Latins characters but not for Chinese character, tried to encode with UTF-8 but seems not work either. Here are the code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
Def Test():
    inputPDF = PdfFileReader('./demo/TESTPDFANNOTATION.pdf', "rb")    
    outputPDF = PdfFileWriter()
       
    pages = inputPDF.getNumPages()
    for p in range(pages):
        outputPDF.addPage(inputPDF.getPage(p))

    outputStream = open('./demo/TESTPDFANNOTATIONOUT.pdf', "wb")
    outputPDF.addJS("var annot = this.addAnnot({ \r \
                    page: 0, \r \
                    type: 'FreeText', \r \
                    contents: '你好', \r \
                    textFont: 'csongl', \r \
                    textSize: 10, \r \
                    rect: [200, 300, 200+150, 300+3*12], // height for three lines \r \
                    width: 1, \r \
                    alignment: 1 \r \
                    });")
    outputPDF.write(outputStream)    
    outputStream.close()
    return("ok")
```

It's weird that If I opened the PDF in notepad text editor, the Chinese characters displayed correctly however when opened with PDF, it shows something like ä½€å¥½, which seems not decoded, since they could be decoded with the online convert tool into almost the right Chinese character, not exactly the same for some cases.
https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode

Any advise would be highly appreciated!

Python version: 3.9+
OS: Win10

Thanks
Stanley

Comment: Thanks K J for the advise, I tried to embed different supportive fonts with PyFPDF (set_fonts function) in the source document and it still does not work. Another related post says annotation with Unicode characters should embed CID font, but have no idea about how to configure this in PyPDF2.

Comment: Haha, not so lucky. That method works when reading in Chinese characters from PDF but not when tried to embed javascript in PDF with Chinese characters. It seems not decoded correctly. Not quite sure if the native package supports or not.

Comment: Thanks @k J, I just found another package PyMuPDF which supports annotations in Chinese perfectly.  Here is the link: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/blob/master/tests/test_annots.py. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, figured out to use another package PyMuPDF to add annotations programmatically with good support of Chinese characters.

```
import fitz

def writeAnnotation():
    blue  = (0,0,1)
    gold  = (1,1,0)

    pdfDoc = fitz.open('./demo/TESTPDFANNOTATION.pdf')
    page = pdfDoc[0]

    rect1 = fitz.Rect(100,100,200,150)

    strContent1= "你好！世界"

    a1 = page.addFreetextAnnot(rect1, strContent1, text_color=blue,  fill_color=gold)

    pdfDoc.save("./demo/TESTPDFANNOTATIONOUT.pdf")
    return("Well done!")
```